# truncate data before save in cakephp 3.6

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

My scenario as below:
I have a table (tbl_a) contain a field 'name' with length is 128 (name VARCHAR(128)).
when user insert data on web application, user puts more than 128 character, but the data was saved with 128 character.
is the any way to configure in cakephp 3.6 in this case?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you want Cake to do in this case? Reject the data as too long? That would fall under validation. Truncate the data for you? I think the database is already handling that. Make the column longer? You can use migrations for that, but it's not something that should happen whenever someone submits overly long data.

Comment: my expectation is when user inputs more than 128 character, only 128 character was saved in database (the text length should be map with maxlength of field in database).

Comment: Didn't you say that's what's already happening?

Comment: in old system was build by cake 1.2, when user inputs more than 128 characters, cake 1.2 will truncate data and insert 128 characters to table (i don't know how to config it), i would like apply this way in cakephp 3.6, are you clear?

Comment: When you enter more than 128 characters in the new version, what happens?

Comment: As @GregSchmidt alluded to are you receiving an error? We understand what you expect to happen, but what is currently happening?

Comment: I have found the cause of problem, this was config in database, not relate to CakePhp Framework. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in some comments, the database will typically truncate the text without complaining, making the save proceed normally.

If you would want this to happen independently of database, you could write this in the `beforeMarshal()` function of the model:

```
public function beforeMarshal(Event $event, ArrayObject $data, ArrayObject $options)
{
    if (isset($data['username']) && strlen($data['username']) > 128) {
        $data['username'] = substr($data['username'], 0, 128); // Truncate
    }
}
```

- **[Cookbook > Table Objects > beforeMarshal](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforemarshal)**